# Display custom field 'Profit' in sales report - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, report, woocommerce

I have been searching for 2 days how to do this and really struggling. I am fairly new to PHP so this maybe really simple, but whatever I try it just doesnt work.

I have a custom field in each product called 'Profit'. All i want to do is call that next to the name of the product in the woocommerce sales Report Email plugin. !

Here is the code from the class-wc-sre-row-top-sellers.php file I need to edit. 
But it doesnt work, where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE: I have now added what was suggested by still no luck. You can see the line I added '// Set Profit by Oli and added the**

. ' - £) . $Profit

at the end of the $value = at the bottom.

**UPDATE2: I have now added the code as I was kindly told below but it is still not working. The profit is being called but nothing is displayed after. The way I have entered the Custom Field is on the products under the Custom Fields tab**

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<?php

if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit;
} // Exit if accessed directly

class WC_SRE_Row_Top_Sellers extends WC_SRE_Report_Row {

 /**
  * The constructor
  *
  * @param $date_range
  *
  * @access public
  * @since  1.0.0
  */
 public function __construct( $date_range ) {
  parent::__construct( $date_range, 'top-sellers', __( 'Top Sellers', 'woocommerce-sales-report-email' ) );
 }

 /**
  * Prepare the data
  *
  * @access public
  * @since  1.0.0
  */
 public function prepare() {

  // Create a Report Manager object
  $report_manager = new WC_SRE_Report_Manager( $this->get_date_range() );

  // Set the default order types
  $order_types = array( 'shop_order' );

  // wc_get_order_types() is a 2.2+ function
  if ( function_exists( 'wc_get_order_types' ) ) {
   $order_types = wc_get_order_types( 'order-count' );
  }

  // Get top sellers
  $top_sellers = $report_manager->get_order_report_data( array(
   'data'         => array(
    '_product_id' => array(
     'type'            => 'order_item_meta',
     'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
     'function'        => '',
     'name'            => 'product_id'
    ),
    '_qty'        => array(
     'type'            => 'order_item_meta',
     'order_item_type' => 'line_item',
     'function'        => 'SUM',
     'name'            => 'order_item_qty'
    )
   ),
   'order_by'     => 'order_item_qty DESC',
   'group_by'     => 'product_id',
   'limit'        => 12,
   'query_type'   => 'get_results',
   'filter_range' => true,
   'order_types'  => $order_types,
  ) );

  $value = 'n/a';

  

  // Fill the $value var with products
  if ( count( $top_sellers ) > 0 ) {
   $value = '';
   foreach ( $top_sellers as $product ) {

// THIS IS WHERE THE NEW CODE IS AND $PROFIT IS CALLED AFTER ' - £' . BELOW
  $Profit = array_shift(woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->product_id, 'Profit', 'names'));
    $value .= $product->order_item_qty . 'x : ' . get_the_title( $product->product_id ) . ' - £' . $Profit . '<br/>';
   }
  }

  $this->set_value( $value );
 }

}
```

Comment: Am also facing the same issue i want to add new rows for **total shipping** and **net sales** in the sales report email. please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to get the custom variable added to woo commerce products:

```
$Profit = array_shift(woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->product_id, 'Profit', 'names'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the post to show where I am implementing this, but i am still not having any luck.

Comment: You have placed it at wrong place, You should add $Profit = array_shift(woocommerce_get_product_terms($product->product_id, 'Profit', 'names'));
 after  foreach ( $top_sellers as $product ) {

Comment: Thanks so much for sending this back and showing me where to put it. Unfortunately this still is not getting the price, its just not grabbing the custom field. It seems "woocommerce_get_product_terms" is deprecated but i have also tried its replacement "wc_get_product_terms" but still no luck. Can anyone help?

Comment: can you add me on Skype: cubicwebdesign

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I have now fixed this. It turns out even though i had posted these as custom fields they had gone in as meta.
  // Fill the $value var with products
  if ( count( $top_sellers ) > 0 ) {
   $value = '';
   foreach ( $top_sellers as $product ) {
$prod_id =  $product->product_id ;
$value .= $product->order_item_qty . 'x : ' . get_the_title( $product->product_id ) . ' - £' . get_post_meta($prod_id, 'Profit', true ) . '<br/>';

Had an error for ages saying : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected "'$product'" (T_VARIABLE) - but this was fixed by replacing a space bfor $product

Comment: I want to add new rows in emails "total shipping" and "net sales" how i can accomplish this?